# Epubjs position of text changes when resizing the book

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, epub.js

I am building an epub reader using epubjs library in reactjs.
The issue i'm facing is when i try to resize the book some contents/text from previous page render or get displayed in the current page.

On initial loading of book `rendition.resize("100%", "100%");`
[image]

When i open the side menu i have to resize the book to fit the content on the screen  `rendition.resize("80%", "100%");`.
[image]

Is there a way in epubjs to fix the content in image1 so that even i resize the book the position of text wont change.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, no there is no way you can make the content appear in the same place or position after resizing,
Epub.js is a responsive book reading library it does not show any default page number of any book because it always adjusts the book container as per user screen size,

when you resize your screen, epub.js fires a "relocated" event which then refreshes the entire epub-Book container

(extra thing!, I don't like the epub.js because after resizing it's all of the functions starting to behave abnormally and it sucks,)